# EF Core extension .Include() not found at test runtime

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, xunit

Previously, our Unit Of Work implementations delivered simple results from the Context, for example

```
    public User Get(int id)
    {
        return Context.Users
            .Single(u => u.Id == id);
    }
```

Yesterday I added relationships to the context as per the following:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
            .HasOne(ur => ur.User)
            .WithMany(u => u.UserRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId);
```

and then also included these navigation properties in the UoW, for example:

```
    public override User Get(int id)
    {
        return Context.Users
            .Include(u => u.UserRoles)
            .Single(u => u.Id == id);
    }
```

The result is that now, the unit tests fail with the following:

> There is no method 'Include' on type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions' that matches the specified arguments

Stack Trace:

> at System.Linq.EnumerableRewriter.FindMethod(Type type, String name, ReadOnlyCollection'1 args, Type[] typeArgs)
>      at System.Linq.EnumerableRewriter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(ReadOnlyCollection`1 nodes)
>      at System.Linq.EnumerableRewriter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
>      at System.Linq.EnumerableQuery'1.GetEnumerator()
>      at System.Linq.EnumerableQuery'1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List'1..ctor(IEnumerable'1 collection)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable'1 source)
>      at RetroNinja.Dal.Ef.Tests.ProjectSprintUowTests.ProjectSprint_GetUsers_HasUsers() in D:\Projects\Global Kinetic\RetroNinja\test\RetroNinja.Dal.Ef.Tests\ProjectSprintUowTests.cs:line 81

This only happens when the tests are executed (either in VS or cmd). It compiles and builds with no problem, and the behavior is as expected when actually hosting the web project and browsing, that is to say, I am seeing the result of the navigation properties in my front-end.

I've tried to explicitly reference EF Core 1.0.1 in my unit test project.json file, and add the using clause in the actual text .cs file too, but it makes no difference.

Where do I start troubleshooting for this?

As requested, here is the unit test code:

```
    [Fact]
    public void UserUow_GetUser_HasUser()
    {
        _fakeContext.Object.Role.AddRange(new List<Role>()
        {
            new Role() { Id = 1, Name = "Role 1"},
            new Role() { Id = 2, Name = "Role 2"},
        });
        _fakeContext.Object.UserRole.AddRange(new List<UserRole>()
        {
            new UserRole() { Id = 1, UserId = 1, RoleId = 1, IsActive = true },
            new UserRole() { Id = 2, UserId = 1, RoleId = 2, IsActive = true }
        });
        _fakeContext.Object.User.Add(new User() { Id = 1, Username = "User 1" });

        User user = UserUow.Get(1);
        Assert.NotNull(user);
        Assert.True(user.Id == 1);
        Assert.NotNull(user.UserRoles);
        Assert.True(user.UserRoles.Count == 2);
        Assert.True(user.UserRoles.ToList()[0].Role.Id == 1);
        Assert.True(user.UserRoles.ToList()[1].Role.Id == 2);
    }
```

Comment: That's a bit strange. Can you also share the test code?

Comment: @Fabio I've added it to the post.

Comment: What is the type/construction of the _fakeContext object?